# VS 2022 c++ application - writing an entry to a .rc file

Tags: c++

I have a c++ app where I use LoadString to read string entries from an embedded .rc file.  Is there a way to write append/update string entries like a WriteString?

Looking for a way to write to a resource file within a c++ app

Comment: That's the wrong solution to a problem you forgot to describe.

Comment: The application contains an .rc file which contains a download URL and command line parameters for the app to be downloaded.   This app downloads the file and launches it with the supplied cmd line params.  This will change occasionally.   The folks who launch the builds aren't developers and may not have access to VS and need the simplest way possible to provide this info to create a build.

Comment: @loloERO Wouldn't any of the suggestions I made work? That's how most programs have kept their data stored for a long time - short of actually requiring a program update where you trigger a download and installation of a new version of the program with the updated rc data.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such function. Programs are usually installed in places where the user running them does not have permission to change files - so the ability to change the actual executable is not something that's been requested very often.

I suggest that you store the information somewhere in the `%AppData%` directory or registry instead.

Comment: Also, the executable is locked by the OS while it is running. So it can't modify itself anyway, regardless of where it is installed.